# How to create an Nginx location block to serve site on subpath of domain

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, drupal

I am working on a legacy Drupal 7 application. My goal is that when the user navigates to [www.example.com/test](http://www.example.com/test), Nginx translates this as [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). I know I need some rewrite rules, but I have been going in circles now and nothing is working as expected. Its important that this solution does not issue a 301/302 etc but does an internal rewrite

I was expecting something like this to work:

```
    location ~ /test {
        rewrite ^/test(/.*)?$ /test/index.php?q=$1 last;
        try_files $uri $uri/ test/index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

I tried messing with the global $base_url value as well and nothing seems to be working at all. I am not a pro at nginx configuration at all, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, if you have any suggestions of good ways to debug this myself, that would be great.

EDIT:
Here are the relevant PHP logs after hitting `/test`:

```
[30-Mar-2023 13:27:01] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
- -  30/Mar/2023:13:27:06 +0000 "GET /test/index.php" 404
```

Comment: Could you share the `access.log` please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know the result:

```
    location  /test {
        rewrite ^/test(/.*)?$ /$1;
        try_files $uri $uri/ test/index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't help, I still get a 404

Comment: This is what I get in the access log: `192.168.204.0 - - [30/Mar/2023:13:22:12 +0000] "GET /test HTTP/2.0" 404 3477 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: What is the `root` or `alias` in the configuration? Is something there?